# How to sum values based on two criterias

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vba7

I'm trying to sum values based on two criteria: category and month (Renew).
I want to sum categories by renew month.
So, for things renewed in March, sum separately by category, but what is monthly and have the same category, must be summed too.

[Example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPCbu.png)

For example:
I have Softwares / Apps / Sites category that have different renew dates (March, April, May, June, September and also monthly).
So, I need to separate and sum values by month, but what are "monthly" have to be summed on all months.
Like this:

> ##### Softwares / Apps / Sites category
>
> - march:  26,50
> - april: 24,90
> - may: 30,60
> - june: 64
> - september: 24,90

Hope I made it clear...
I'm going crazy with that... please, help me...

Comment: Why not add a column calculating the monthly (if Anual, value/12,value)

Answer (score 0):

For March:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B1000*(C2:C1000="Softwares / Apps / Sites")*(((E2:E1000="Monthly")+(E2:E1000="March"))>0))
```

Categories and month can be refer to cell. In the picture I can't see column, change them with real layout.

Answer (score 0):

My table data is this:

```
Description,Price,Category,Period,Renew,Day
Netflix.Com,9,Streaming,Monthly,Monthly,5
Disney Plus,11,Streaming,Monthly,Monthly,5
Amazonprime,8,Streaming,Monthly,Monthly,5
Youtube,8,Softwares/Apps/Sites,Monthly,Monthly,5
Spotify,6,Softwares/Apps/Sites,Monthly,Monthly,5
Google,15,Work,Monthly,Monthly,5
Bank Fees,5,Bank Taxes,Monthly,Monthly,5
Internet,20,Streaming,Monthly,Monthly,5
Healthcare,20,Health,Monthly,Monthly,5
Smart Fit,35,Academy,Annual,June,10
Cellphone Plan,20,Work,Annual,June,10
Backup sw,12.5,Softwares/Apps/Sites,Annual,March,20
Office 365,50,Softwares/Apps/Sites,Annual,June,15
Truecaller,10.9,Softwares/Apps/Sites,Annual,September,10
Kasperksy,10.9,Softwares/Apps/Sites,Annual,April,10
Canva,5.7,Work,Annual,May,15
Kasperksy,10.9,Softwares/Apps/Sites,Annual,May,15
Canva,5.7,Work,Annual,May,5
```

(To make it easier to answer your questions, please export the data as CSV, then use four leading spaces to format the data in your question - it saves me five minutes typing in the data, and potentially making errors).

The command to use is `SUMIFS`. The syntax is:

```
SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2], …)
```

So, if the entire table is located between A1 and F19, I could do this:

```
=SUMIFS($B$1:$B$19, $C$1:$C$19,"Softwares/Apps/Sites",$D$1:$D$19,"Monthly")
```

With my data, a total of 14.